# A Galois equivariant Weil cohomology theory with coefficients in the rational numbers and a variation of the Tate/Hodge conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, motives, p-adic-numbers, algebraic-cycles

A well-known example of Serre shows that there can be no Weil cohomology theory with $\mathbb Q$ coefficients for schemes over $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. However, this example is no obstruction to a Weil cohomology theory for schemes over $\mathbb Q_p$ (or some local field $K$ containing it). Indeed, given $X/K$, and an embedding $\iota: K \subset \mathbb C$, we can define a Weil cohomology theory with $\mathbb Q$ coefficients by
$$ H^i(X) = H^i_{\text{sing}}(X(\mathbb C),\mathbb Q) $$
where the $\mathbb C$ points of $X$ are taken relative to $\iota$. Unfortunately, this cohomology theory is not functorial with the action of the Galois group $\Gamma = \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ unlike usual 'etale cohomology.

**Question 1:** Is there any obstruction to a $\mathbb Q$-Weil cohomology theory $H^i_W$ for schemes over $K$ that is functorial with an action of the Galois group $\Gamma$ on $H^i_W\otimes \mathbb Q_p$? In particular, could we have such a theory with a $\Gamma$ equivariant, sufficiently nice (for eg., commuting with cycle class maps) isomorphism
$$ H^i_{\text{\'et}}(X_{\overline K},\mathbb Q_p) \cong H^i_W(X)\otimes\mathbb Q_p ?$$

**Motivation:** In particular, I have in mind a specific application for such a theory. As [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73270/tate-conjecture-for-elliptic-curves-local-fields) answer shows, the naive analogue of the Tate conjecture is false over local fields. However, I wonder if the following version might be true...

Suppose we have a nice cohomology theory $H^i_W$ as above. Then the cycle class map would be of the form
$$ Z^i(X) \to (H^{2i}_W(X)\otimes\mathbb Q_p(-i))^{\Gamma}. $$
Could it be true that every class in $H^i(W)$ whose image in $(H^{2i}_W(X)\otimes\mathbb Q_p(-i))$ is $\Gamma$ stable is in the image of the cycle class map?