# 2-dimensional absolutely irreducible $p$-adic Galois reps

Tags: p-adic-hodge-theory

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/55808/138661) the following is stated:

> It's a basic fact in $p$-adic Hodge theory that any 2-dim. absolutely
>   irreducible $G_{\mathbb Q_p}$-representation with distinct Hodge-Tate weights is uniquely determined by $a_p$.

Could somebody explain in maximum detail why is this true? Taking inspiration from the famous ELI5 communication style, explain like I am a generic first-year grad student.

Comment: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao which part, exactly?

Comment: Specifically, Theorem 8.3.6 and its proof. They really spell it out in full detail, to the point where I, as someone who was completely unfamiliar with $p$-adic Hodge theory, could understand after a few hours worth of work.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao oh well, problem solved then. Thanks. You can post it as an answer, so this is not in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [these](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf) notes on Hodge theory, Th. 8.3.6.