# Uncountably many non-isomorphic Tate modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, galois-representations, motives

Do there exist uncountably many abelian surfaces with good reduction over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with pairwise non-isomorphic rational $p$-adic Tate modules?

If we took $l$-adic Tate modules there would be countably many at most by a result of Kisin and the fact that the moduli of ppav is of finite type.

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/55808) would suggest that there is only countably many $p$-adic Tate modules for elliptic curves with good reduction.

Is it at least true that there are uncountably many non-isomorphic crystalline representations of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ coming from geometry?

Comment: Given an abelian variety $A$ over a finite field $k$ its lifts to abelian schemes over $W(k)$ are in bijection with rank $g$ saturated submodules of $H^1_{cris}(A/W(k))$ that reduce mod $p$ to the 1st step of the Hodge filtration and are isotropic for the cup product so they are parametrized by  (the $W(k)[1/p]$-points of) a residue disk in the isotropic Grassmanian. The isomorphism classes of Galois representations are then parametrized by the quotient of this disk by $Aut_{\varphi} H^1_{cris}(A)[1/p]$.

Comment: If the dimension of this algebraic group is less than $g(g+1)/2$ then the quotient has uncountably many points. This happens e.g. if $A$ is the product of $4$ pairwise non-isogenous elliptic curves, for in that case the automorphisms of a $\varphi$-module is an $8$-dimensional group and $g(g+1)/2=10$. Maybe this happens in smaller dimensions as well because the action on the Grassmanian is not free, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *4 pairwise non-isogenous ordinary elliptic curves

Comment: May you explain why any lift of this sort gives an abelian scheme over $W(k)$ indeed?

Comment: @MikhailBondarko Sorry, I forgot to mention that we should pick a polarization on $A$ of degree prime to $p$ (let's assume that $A$ has such, if it doesn't then the question of existence of algebraizable deformations becomes subtler), it induces a perfect pairing on $H^1_{cris}$, and the claim is that lifts of the Hodge filtration isotropic for this pairing give lifts of the abelian variety that admit a lift of the polarizing line bundle.

Comment: Deformations of abelian schemes are unobstructed and one can use that to show that any lift of the Hodge filtration is realized by a lift of $A$ to a formal abelian scheme (for a reference, see e.g. Messing's "Crystals associated to Barsotti-Tate group", though there the approach is slightly different). The chosen polarization lifts to a given formal lift if and only if the lift of the Hodge filtration is isotropic. this is because the obstruction to lifting a line bundle onto $\mathfrak{A}$ is the image of its crystalline Chern class in the group $H^2(\mathfrak{A},\mathcal{O})$.

Comment: It vanishes if and only if the Chern class lies in $Fil^1H^2_{dR}(\mathfrak{A})$ which is equivalent to the vanishing of the induced pairing on $Fil^1H^1_{dR}(\mathfrak{A})$. Since a projective formal scheme is algebrizable, a lift of ample line bundle allows us to produce an abelian scheem out of a formal lift.